# How to fix no output with python linked to php?

Tags: php, python

I have a python script which takes data from a csv file via pandas. When I run this solely this works fine. But when I run it within php it does not work. I want it to work like that so I can output the python output onto the website.

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd

teams = pd.read_csv("/var/www/html/teams.csv")
print(str(teams['punt'][0]))
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/html/python.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Under the PHP is some irrelevant html code. It would be very helpful if someone could help me!

EDIT:

When I run the php in terminal it does not give any errors and it gives the result perfectly. But when I run localhost it does not work but I cannot seem to find any errors. I also tried running a different python script which only prints "hello" and when I try that the code does work and the text shows up in the browser.

Comment: can you pls provide the result given by php?

Comment: [Are you sure you need to elaborate the CSV in Python and not directly in PHP?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: @bracco23 I could do that but I am going to do some work on the script after this and I am more familiar with Python than with PHP.